# Array as session variable

Tags: php, arrays, session

Is it possible to make an array a session variable in PHP?

The situation is that I have a table (page 1) with some cells having a link to a particular page. The next page will have a list of names (page 2, which I want to keep in a session array) with their respective checkboxes. On submitting this form, it will lead to a transaction page (page 3, where values of posted checkboxes are kept in a database for corresponding names). Now, if I return to the first page and click another cell, will the session array contain the new list of names or the old ones?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, PHP supports arrays as session variables.  See [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20080707052007/http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7) for an example.

As for your second question: once you set the session variable, it will remain the same until you either change it or [`unset`](http://fr.php.net/session_unset) it.  So if the 3rd page doesn't change the session variable, it will stay the same until the 2nd page changes it again.

Comment: If you go back to the first page and click through to the second page (where the data is put into a session) the session data will contain a new set of data.

Comment: The Listing 13 of the example page is pretty bad example. It confuses readers.

Answer (score 85):

Yes, you can put arrays in sessions, example:

```
$_SESSION['name_here'] = $your_array;
```

Now you can use the `$_SESSION['name_here']` on any page you want but make sure that you put the `session_start()` line before using any session functions, so you code should look something like this:

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['name_here'] = $your_array;
```

**Possible Example:**

```
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['name_here'] = $_POST;
```

Now you can get field values on any page like this:

```
 echo $_SESSION['name_here']['field_name'];
```

As for the second part of your question, the session variables remain there unless you assign different array data:

```
 $_SESSION['name_here'] = $your_array;
```

Session life time is set into **php.ini** file.

**[More Info Here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)**

Comment: Hi, can I add more  to the array, `$_SESSION['name_here']['field_2'] = 'xxx';`

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php // PHP part
    session_start();          // Start the session
    $_SESSION['student']=array(); // Makes the session an array
    $student_name=$_POST['student_name']; //student_name form field name
    $student_city=$_POST['city_id'];   //city_id form field name
    array_push($_SESSION['student'],$student_name,$student_city);   
    //print_r($_SESSION['student']);
?>

<table class="table">     <!-- HTML Part (optional) -->
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
                                                        
    <tr>
     <?php for($i = 0 ; $i < count($_SESSION['student']) ; $i++) {
     echo '<td>'.$_SESSION['student'][$i].'</td>';
     }  ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

First change the array to a string by using [implode()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp) function. For Ex **:**

```
$number = array(1,2,3,4,5);

# Implode into a string using | as the separator.
$stringofnumber = implode('|', $number);

# Pass the string to a session. e.g
$_SESSION['string'] = $stringofnumber;
```

So when you go to the page where you want to use the array, just explode your string. For Ex **:**

```
# Required before $_SESSION can be accessed.
session_start();

# Explode back to an array using | as the needle.
$number=explode('|', $_SESSION['string']);
```

You array is now the value of `$number`.