# question in sessions and array

Tags: php, arrays, session

i have session code

it's working fine

but some friend told me this code should not work !

but it's work fine with me !

i try code on localhost

so my question is , if i uploaded this code to my server

it will work fine like localhost ?

or will not work like my friend said ?

my code is

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['news'][] = 'First';
$_SESSION['news'][] = 'Second';
print_r($_SESSION['news']);
```

its print
Array ( [0] => First [1] => Second )

and that's what i want !
it's fine ..

Comment: So your question is: "There is no problem, but what _can_ fail?"? Why you don't just ask your friend, whats the problem with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work definitely.
Or to be more safe you can do like following before assigning it values.

```
    $_SESSION['news'] = array();
```

Comment: Thank you all

i was scare from errors 

but now i decided to use it

Answer (score 1):

Your friend is wrong. You can use arrays as session variables.

For supporting arguments, please see [array as session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable) and [Can I Store An Array In A Session?](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/intro-php-sessions/7).

Answer (score 0):

It seems okay to me. There's no reason why it shouldn't work on your server.

Answer (score 0):

After 5 hours of tests ,,

it's seems not work like my friend said !

he was right

for first time i used this way , i got an error

but i ingored it , because it's did not happin again !

but the error is show in first time only !

i browsed the page from another browser

i got that error !

i forget to save the error , but it's say you can not use empty []

after all , iam now use it as numbers

and thank you again and sorry for my language