# PHP Multi-dimensional arrays

Tags: php

I'm banging my head trying to get my mind around this.  I have worked with arrays before but I seem to be struggling with them in PHP.  Trust me I've looked at questions here and other places so I apologize upfront for how basic this question probably is.  What I'm trying to do is make an array of an array???

basically, I'm trying to make a session global variable so that it stores an array and that can be continually added to.

```
$_SESSION['school'] = array('events' => array());
```

example of the events array would be:

```
events['name'] = 'Homecoming';
events['date'] = 'December 15, 2012';
events['cost'] = 18.00;
events['attending'] = array();
events['attending'][$i] = 'John'
```

The use then would be something be

```
echo $_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['name']; 
echo $_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['date']; 
echo $_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['cost'];
```

...

I've tried creating it as mentioned above and populating like this (again an array of events array)

```
$_SESSION['school'] = array('events' => array());

$_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['name'] = 'Homecoming';
$_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['date'] = 'December 15, 2012';
$_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['cost'] = 18.00;
$_SESSION['school'][$i][events]['people'] = array('jane', 'john', 'bill');
```

This doesn't seem to work because I can tell the count is going up as it is being populated.  I've tried a few other ways but for some reason I haven't been able to figure it out.  Most examples I've come across don't appear to be similar to what I'm trying do.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

--------UPDATED QUESTION BASED ON FEEDBACK--------
I think I'm very close to understanding you're updated logic and I tried updating my code but I'm running into the following issue.  I have an initialization php script which sets $_SESSION['school'] = array(array());.  This doesn't get populated until later and at one point I do a check on $_SESSION['school'] with count. It always returns 1 on the intial check even though nothing was added.  However, I assume its because it holds one empty array.  So it makes me question the structure. 
Since I'm a visual person this is what I think I need but I'm not sure how to construct it.

```
//would be an 1 dimensional array that empty until a school is added later on in code.
$_SESSION['school'] = array();
```

it's elements would hold a multidimensional array with elements

```
['name'] = 'Johnson High';
['address'] = '121 elm';
['city'] = 'san jose';
['state'] = 'California';
['events'] = array();
```

['events']  is empty until events are added but here are some items it would contain

```
['events']['name'] = 'homecoming';
['events']['date'] = 'December 15, 2012';
['events']['cost'] = '18.00';
```

in the end the $_SESSION['school'] could hold 1 to many schools that I could loop through.

Now to my misunderstanding of danL updated logic, I don't see how name and events would have the same index?  When I look at the code I get a sense that the the $_SESSION['school'] would look like this

```
$_SESSION['school']{ 'name' => 'Johnson High',
                     'events' => array('basketball', 'soccer', 'football'),
                     'name' => 'West Forsyth High',
                     'events' => array('basketball', 'soccer', 'football')};
```

If that's the case then each element is at a different index.  I must be missing something fundamental here.  I'm continually trying to read up and make the connection to what I'm doing wrong.  I think I'm just looking at the problem from the wrong angle.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2306168/1726801

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so based on the help of danL (thanks so much).  I've figured out what I need to do.  So in my initialization script I set,

```
$_SESSION['school'] = array();
```

after further processing I create a events array to store the info in.

```
$event = arra();
$event['name'] = 'Homecoming';
$event['date'] = 'December 15, 2012';
$event['cost'] = '18.00';
$event['people'] = array();
$event['people'] = { 'john', 'mary', 'mark', 'janice'};
```

the last two lines could probably be joined into one line.

then I add the event array to the school array as,

```
$_SESSION['school'][] = $event;
```

I don't know how I get spun around so easily with associative arrays but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the key in quotes if it isn't a numeric key, like this:

```
$_SESSION['school']['events']['name'] = 'Homecoming';
```

But if you're wanting to do something like you did here:

```
echo $_SESSION['school'][$i]['events']['name'];
```

then you would need to declare your $_SESSION['school'] variable like this:

```
$_SESSION['school'] = array(array('events' => array()));
```

If you notice, the way you've declared the $_SESSION['school'] array, there are only 3 dimensions, but you are trying to access 4 dimensions in the section where you're using the $i variable to reference indexes inside the array.

UPDATE: This is how you would add events to an empty school array

```
$_SESSION['school'] = array(array());
$_SESSION['school'][]['name'] = 'Johnson High';
$_SESSION['school'][]['events'] = array('basketball', 'soccer', 'football');
$_SESSION['school'][]['name'] = 'West Forsyth High';
$_SESSION['school'][]['events'] = array('theater', 'football', 'lacrosse');
```

Then you could loop through them like this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['school']); $i++) {
   echo 'School name: ' . $_SESSION['school'][$i]['name'] . '<br />';
   echo 'Events:<br />';
   foreach($_SESSION['school'][$i]['events'] as $event) {
      echo $event . '<br />';
   }  
   echo '<br />';
}
```

This would output:

```
School name: Johnson High
Events:
basketball
soccer
football

School name: West Forsyth High
Events:
theater
football
lacrosse
```

I hope that is what you're asking for. Sorry if I don't understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe I still need to take a step back.  So lets say I have $_session['school']=array(); couldn't I do $_session['school'][$i] = 'Johnson high';  school is an array and $i the index?  Or am I screwing up the concepts between a normal array and an associative array?  I think I must be.

Comment: That would work fine. You can add items to the array like this:

$_SESSION['school'] = array();
$_SESSION['school'][] = 'Johnson High';
$_SESSION['school'][] = 'West Forsyth High';

$i = 0; // this could be inside a loop of course
echo $_SESSION['school'][$i]; // echoes Johnson High

Comment: What do the closed brackets do?  The more I thought about it the more my nose bleed, jk.  So let say I have this array,  $animals = array( 'tiger', 'bee', 'dog').  How would I add cat, with push? Or could I do $animals[3] = 'cat';

Comment: Yes, you could do $animals[3] = 'cat'; but that is why I did the empty brackets. If you don't specify an index, it will just append the new item to the end of the array. So in this case, $animals[] = 'cat'; does the exact same thing as $animals[3] = 'cat';

Comment: Ok, understood.  So going back to the original question.  So I have school array of events.  I don't quite understand how to start with a empty school array and add a bunch event arrays that I can later loop through.  I appreciate your patience and help

Comment: I have updated my answer with new code which explains how to add a school to the array and define it's name and list of events. Then it loops through and shows you the school names and list of events. I hope this is what you were asking for.

Comment: Thanks danL for all your help and I think I'm close but I've updated my question above based on your recommendations.