# Passing an array from one page to another in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, session

I have a register form (for events) in which the number of fields input are not same. It depends upon the events. Different events limit different numbers of members for registration. So, in my `events` TABLE I've a row `members` which store the number of members.

So,finally my registration form goes like this:

```
if ($row['members']>1){
    echo "Hello ".$sess_name.", you can add ".($row['members']-1)." more members to register for ".$row['name']."<br>";
    echo "On successful registration of the event, all the team members will receive an email on their registered email ids<br>";
    $mem=array();?>
    <form action="" method="post">
    <?php for ($i=1;$i<$row['members'];$i++){
        echo '<label>Insert ID of Member '.$i.' :</label>';
        echo '<input type="text" id="id" size="20" name="'.$mem[].'"><br>';
    }
    echo '<button type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" name="register1">Register</button>';?>
    </form>
```

I'm storing the `ID` that are being input in an array(`$mem`)
But I don't know how to pass it (`$mem`) in another page to store it in MySQL table.

Comment: have you tried session variables?

Comment: @spin_eight:I know how to pass session variables but I don't know how the procedure will change when passing arrays. Please help.

Comment: ok, no problem, refer, for ex., to the following topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable

Answer (score 0):

Add an hidden input field

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php for ($i=1;$i<$row['members'];$i++){
    echo '<label>ID of Member '.$i.' :</label>';
    echo '<input type="text" id="email" size="20" name="'.$mem[].'"><br>';
    echo '<input type="hidden" id="userID" name="userID[]" value='.$i.'>';
}
echo '<button type="submit" id="submit" value="Register" name="register1">Register</button>';?>
</form>
```

Comment: And, after that how will I pass it to another page and store in MySQL Table?

Comment: By submitting the form, the userID will be available on the next page (depends on the target of your `<form>`).
Passing it further is again possible by using a form or an ajax call, depending on your needs.

Comment: I want to store the `$mem()` elements. Those are the things that will be input by the user. Please see my edited question.