# PHP - Nested associative array in a $_SESSION array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I was wondering is it possible to have an associative array within a session array? If so, what would be the best way to do it and how can I loop through it? I have tried the following but it doesnt seem to work:

```
//The variables are post variables from a form
$_SESSION['users'][$id] = array('name'=>$name, 'status'=>$status, 'salary'=>"20000");
```

Here is how I am trying to loop through the session array:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['users'] as $id=>$value) {
echo $value;
}
```

Also, If I knew an id how can I get the name? Can I do `$_SESSION['users']['1234']['name']`?

Comment: Yes, it is possible as the value is serialized for storage. Post the rest of your code so we can see what is causing the problem.

Comment: this is answer for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable/2306168#2306168

Comment: Try doing `$_SESSION['users'] = array();` first...

Comment: Why are you storing session info for multiple users in the same session???

Comment: Anything that can be serialized (run through [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)) can be put into `$_SESSION`. That means strings, arrays, numbers, stdClasses etc., but **not** most resources/file handles/sockets.

Comment: It does not make sense to store more than the currents' user information into a session.

Comment: @crypticツ My attempted code is now included

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can have an associative array within a session array.  You can also loop through it with a `for` or a `foreach` loop.  e.g.:

```
$array = $_SESSION['users'][$id];

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    var_dump($array[$key]); //Will dump info about a single element
}
```

However, it would be helpful to see your error message or additional details of what you are trying to do and what about it that isn't working.

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question, since you are accessing and array of arrays (theoretically) you would need to nest a foreach with another foreach to get at your values.

```
foreach($_SESSION['users'] as $arrays) {
    foreach($arrays as $arrKey => $arrVal) {
        var_dump($arrays[$arrKey]);
    }
}
```

Running that on your data would output (with my own fake data to fill variables):

```
string(7) "johndoe"
string(6) "active"
string(5) "20000"
```

Comment: Also, If I knew an id how can I get the name? Can I do $_SESSION['users']['1234']['name']?

Comment: @Matt9Atkins Yes you can, so long as `['name']` is a valid key inside the `['1234']` array.

Comment: @Matt9Atkins I've updated my answer based on your updated question.  Hopefully that helps you out some more.