# Pass PHP array to HTML Page.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

**What I want to be able to is on button click I want to check a Server-Side directory for the existence of certain files.**

**If they exist I wish to display a checkbox corresponding to that file.**

So far I have managed to use **PHP** and **AJAX** to check if the files exist or not and write to and array: 1 if the file exists, and a 0 if not.

Now...what I need to do at this stage is call upon this array, from my PHP file, or write this array to a div on my main HTML page. However when I go to echo it navigates away from my Main.html, opening a new page and writing on that.

Big question is can I write the array on my main html page from my *PHP_Function.php* file.

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <form action="PHP_Function.php">
        <input type="submit" class="learnButton" name="insert" value="Find Available Evidence" />   

    </form>


    <form action="available_evidence">
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Facebook<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" checked> Facebook Messenger<br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Twitter<br>
    </form>
```

With the following array within PHP_function.php file:

```
if(in_array("Facebook.xml", $dirArray)){


    $IfPresentArray[0]="1";

    }else {

    $IfPresentArray[0]="0";
}
foreach ($IfPresentArray as $value) {

    echo "$value<br />\n";
}
```

I am very new to PHP and HTML, and I have been banging my head off the wall with this for a while now.

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Answer (score 1):

You are using AJAX so all your communication will need to go back and forth over that medium.  In brief, your PHP script (the one called by ajax) will `echo` JSON values (typically created by `json_encode($myarray)`) and this will then be available to your javascript over on your client-side.

A quick [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+ajax+json+example&gws_rd=ssl) for "jquery ajax json example" should get you some good, helpful ideas of how it fits together.

Here's the client-side from [one of those google links above](http://www.lennu.net/jquery-ajax-example-with-json-response/) - note the `.done` part

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(':submit').on('click', function() { // This event fires when a button is clicked
    var button = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({ // ajax call starts
      url: 'serverside.php', // JQuery loads serverside.php
      data: 'button=' + $(this).val(), // Send value of the clicked button
      dataType: 'json', // Choosing a JSON datatype
    })
    .done(function(data) { // Variable data contains the data we get from serverside
      $('#wines').html(''); // Clear #wines div

      if (button == 'all') { // If clicked buttons value is all, we post every wine
        for (var i in data.red) {
          $('#wines').append('Red wine: ' + data.red[i] + '<br/>');
        }
        for (var i in data.white) {
          $('#wines').append('White wine: ' + data.white[i] + '<br/>');
        }
      }
      else if (button == 'red') { // If clicked buttons value is red, we post only red wines
        for (var i in data) {
          $('#wines').append('Red wine: ' + data[i] + '<br/>');
        }
      }
      else if (button == 'white') { // If clicked buttons value is white, we post only white wines
        for (var i in data) {
          $('#wines').append('White wine: ' + data[i] + '<br/>');
        }
      }
    });
    return false; // keeps the page from not refreshing 
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your array inside a `$_SESSION` variable, but you'll have to use a `session_start();` on both pages.

On your php page, use: `$_SESSION['array'] = $array;` and then on your main page retrieve the array by the inverse: `$array = $_SESSION['array'];`.

You can now use said array on your main page.
To retrieve a specific value: `$value1 = $_SESSION['array'][0];`

For further reference:

[Array as session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable)