# PHP: Storing Data in Array for Global Use Across Scripts

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array, singleton

I have an XML file in my PHP web application that does not get updated frequently. On first time page load I want to parse the XML only once and store data results in multi-dimensional array.

I am looking for best way to store this data so parsing XML does not occur more than once when navigating throughout web application pages.

I tried Singleton but it does not work the same way as in, for example, Java because it lives as long as script runs, meaning every page load has a new singleton instance.

What are other best approaches to store data in PHP? Session? Why so? Anything else? I want it to be simple and without any additional installations.

Thanks

Comment: You could store it in a file or memcache.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable

Comment: I tried storing in a session but it does not seem to save the multi-dimensional array format. It looks like only top elements are saved and all children are gone.