# How to pass array with str_slipt to another page

Tags: php, arrays, database

I convert various strings in one array that in one page for after put in database in another page.

```
$menuId = str_split($_SESSION['menuId'] = $mostrar['menuId']);

var_dump($menuId);
```

That is the output i have in first page.

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" }
```

In second page i have that output.

```
string(0) ""
```

I need to be the same array to insert in database but that is not happening.

My code is:

```
        $id_resp = (isset($_POST['id_resp']) ? $_POST['id_resp'] : '');
        $id = $_SESSION['UtilizadorID'];
        $data = (isset($_POST['data']) ? $_POST['data'] : '');
        //$menuId = $_SESSION['menuID'];
         $menuId = (isset($_POST['menuId']) ? $_POST['menuId'] : '');

        var_dump($menuId);


          $option = isset($_POST['corp_resp']) ? $_POST['corp_resp'] : false;
   if ($option) {          
      foreach ( $option as $corp_resp ) 
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO respostas (id_resp, corp_resp,id,data,menuId) VALUES ('','" . $corp_resp . "','" . $id . "', NOW( ) , '$menuId')")  or die("Alguma coisa correu mal durante o registo. MySQL erro: ".mysql_error());
   } else {                                                          
     echo "task option is required";
     exit;
```

Comment: Put `$menuId` on the session in first script and then get it out of session in the second script

Comment: You are looking for `$menuId` in `$_POST['menuId']`. Did you put this value into a forms `<input>` field? If so show us how and show the HTML for the form

Comment: _Just in case you are very confused_ `var_dump()` might put text on a page, but you cannot use that text in the next script. All data sent from the browser to the form script must be inside `<form>` tags and in some sort of `<input>` field

Comment: What is given the 4,5,6 is the variable $mostrar['menuId']). I have table where have that values and i want to pass that to insert. The only value is a form is corp_resp. The anothers are values passed in another pages.

Comment: I can´t pass that array page by page in session?

Comment: Yes you can, just make sure every page does a `session_start()` at the top of the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to post that array you can do it using [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) method as below.

```
<input type="hidden"
  id="menuId"
  name="menuId"
  value="<?php print base64_encode(serialize($menuId)) ?>">;
```

After post you can [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) as below and use it.

```
$menuId= $_POST["menuId"];
$menuId = unserialize(base64_decode($menuId));
```

**OR**

You can also use session variable for the same.

```
$_SESSION['menuId'] = $menuId
```

See the reference [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable)

Comment: Maybe i doing wrong but is not that i want. That value 4,5,6 is from one table where i want to sent too to database correlate with the values insert in form in corp_resp.

Comment: Are you getting `$menuId` value in your second page ?

Comment: in avaliações2.php(first page)  $menuId = str_split($_SESSION['menuId'] = $mostrar['menuId']); i do var_dump of menuId and i have array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "4" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "5" } array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "6" } i want to have the same in second page. What is sending the 4,5,6 is mostrar. And mostrar is reading for database where is menuIdPai=2. If you have another question please feel free to ask.