# PHP Session Empty in different PHP Files

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

i have this Code in my first PHP File

```
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION);
echo 'Session-ID: '.session_id();
```

And the Same on a second PHP File. Its same Domain.

In the First file, i can see some Session Informations from Login with CodeIgniter. Here the Result:

```
Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1508770297 [username] => test@test.com [role] => 1 [name] => test@test.com [id] => 1 [login] => 1 ) Session-ID: f9fn1bi0ioucr57d2j050elnca8i0veg
```

On the second file, this is the result

```
Array ( ) Session-ID: f9fn1bi0ioucr57d2j050elnca8i0veg
```

Its the Same Session-ID but i cannot get the username on second file :(

Comment: Is this perhaps what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/a/2306168/1607393

Comment: Nope. I have things in array as you see, but only in one php file. Its same Domain but in 2nd PHP File the Array is Empty... but idk why

Comment: Is there any `www` different in the domain :D

Comment: All www domain. All the Same.

Comment: Why are you using session_start? just use $this->session->set_userdata($data); make sure your session library is loaded ($this->load->library('session');) Read the users guide on the sessions library