# How to hide or translate the URL search parameters?

Tags: php, yii2, internationalization

Right now i'm developing a yii2 powered application, and it needs to support 2 languages.
When searching in a gridview, the resulting url is something like this:

```
books/?BookSearch[code]=&BookSearch[name]=pet
```

Is there a way to translate or hide the search parameters? (hiding would probably be the best option for me).
The books/?BookSearch part could even stay the same, what i want to change is the attributes (in this case code and name)

Comment: Do you want to obfuscate, encrypt, or store in a session? Something else?

Comment: Either obfuscate (the best option) or encrypt

Comment: Use `POST` instead of `GET`?

Comment: Post is slower and asks the user if he wants to send the data again every time he refreshes the page.

Comment: You want to hide `BookSearch` keys or values or both?  Probably most importantly, WHY do you wish to do this?  Do the query strings need to work forever (as a permanent bookmark per say)?  Is it important that is not comprehensible by humans (and who-cares-if-someone-cracks-it) or does it need to be "uncrackable"?

Comment: Both would be great, but just the keys is enough.
It's not to hide something, it's just to be able to have parameters name in a language (in my case italian). I don't want users to see like BookSearch[codice]&BookSearch[nome_libro] etc.
If i can't achieve that, i will use english for models names and attributes, but i have some very specific attribute names which will be hard to translate.

Comment: You should try to create two separate search models for separate languages, and two separate grids which uses correct model. You would need to quite complicated abstraction to support this use case in convenient way, it is probably not worth it if you have only 2 languages (and one form?). But probably the best option would be to give up the whole idea, it will give you more problems than benefits.

Comment: I'm afraid @rob006 is right.

Answer (score -1):

you can set the data into session array and call them on the search page

you can refer to this stack for more info [Array as session variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306159/array-as-session-variable)

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if this is you answer but if you like ofuscate " code " and "name" you can  use  this  to encrypt

> $encryptedData = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->encryptByPassword($data,
>   $secretKey);

and this to decrypt

> $data = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->decryptByPassword($encryptedData,
>   $secretKey);